# mapstruct 1.3 can not get Enum as first method parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, mapstruct

say you have a model class which only has a single Enum variable

```
public class MyModel {

  private MyEnum enum;
  //getter and setter

}
```

and you want to have a mapper method which only maps that single Enum of yours.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyCustomeMapper {

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(source = "enum", target = "enum")
    MyModel toMyModel(MyEnum enum);

}
```

but sadly you get `Can't generate mapping method from enum type to non-enum type` error which is not right here. because both of them are the same Enum. (and no `@valueMapping` does not work as well)

clearly it's mapstruct bug!

**MY SOLUTION**

it might be stupid but it works. all you need to do is to add another method parameter (like a dummy String) as the first method parameter, then your Enum as the second method parameter. you don't need to map your dummy String, just let it be there...

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyCustomeMapper {

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(source = "enum", target = "enum")
    MyModel toMyModel(String dummy, MyEnum enum);

}
```

now the first method parameter is not an Enum so mapstruct won't make you any problem.
anyway, I'm looking for a better solution if there is anything out there.

Comment: Which version of MapStruct is this?

Comment: mapstruct version is 1.3.1 final @Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is only present in MapStruct 1.3. Starting from MapStruct 1.4 it is supported to map between an Enum source parameter into a property in a Bean.